# output of my neuralnetwork is constant

Tags: r

I am using backprop algorithm for predicting prices.i am using neuralnet package. my neural network has one hidden layer with 4 nodes. output of my network is constant and changing very slightly. i have normalised my data. what can be the problem

my neuralnet

```
      nn<- neuralnet(O.avgprice+O.firstquartil+O.thirdquartil~Timestamp+avg.price+weekday+firstquartil+thirdquartil+nooftransactions,
                 data = trainANN,hidden = c(4), algorithm = "backprop", rep = "1",learningrate = 0.01, threshold = 0.01, linear.output = F)
```

nn$net.result[[1]]

```
      [,1] [,2]                 [,3]
     96121    1    1 0.000000018657606331
     24801    1    1 0.000000015347274146
     54704    1    1 0.000000017414965756
     54319    1    1 0.000000019182735544
     89317    1    1 0.000000019540763609
     34027    1    1 0.000000018349857324
     59145    1    1 0.000000018922293155
     93596    1    1 0.000000019104633387
     42171    1    1 0.000000018486794230
     77026    1    1 0.000000019084768899
     50876    1    1 0.000000017692360018
     83098    1    1 0.000000018162597292
     26539    1    1 0.000000014943126974
     88331    1    1 0.000000019915268711
     66083    1    1 0.000000019481553856
```

this is how i normalised my data

```
    maxs <- apply(m1,2,max)
    mins <- apply(m1,2,min)
    ANN <- as.data.frame(scale(m1,center = mins, scale = maxs - mins ))
```

please let me know if any more information is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lapply performs better in scaling/normalising data of large volumes
 m <- function(x) {(x - min(x, na.rm=TRUE))/(max(x,na.rm=TRUE) - 
                                             min(x, na.rm=TRUE))} 

N <- as.data.frame(lapply(m1, doit))
```

Comment: could you explain a little to why this works? to assist with future readers development?